# Simple image data being received from other apps has a resolution smaller than or equal to 0

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I followed [Google's guide Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) and I managed to get the uri as promised, my app icon is being shown when an image is to be shared.

Yet there is a specific problem, this is how it goes:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
    }
}
```

`handleSendImage(intent);` leads to

```
void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        pfadPhoto = getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, imageUri);
        i("handleSendImage "+pfadPhoto);
        fBildVerkleinern(pfadPhoto);
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = uri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

`fBildVerkleinern(pfadPhoto);` leads to

```
private void fBildVerkleinern(String bildpfad) {
...
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
int ivBreite = iv.getWidth();
int ivHoehe = iv.getHeight();
...
v = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bildpfad); //bildpfad = pfadPhoto
...
 bitmap2 = getResizedBitmap(v,(int)((float)ivBreite / vergroesserungsFaktor),ivBreite);
...
}
```

`getResizedBitmap` leads to

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    if (bm != null) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and `Bitmap.createBitmap` leads to

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

Yet I also have an `onActivityResult` that is run after a picture selection takes place with the file manager which looks like

```
if (requestCode == CHOOSE_PHOTO) {
    if (data == null) {
        f("Fehler");
        return;
    }
    pfadPhoto = getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
    fBildVerkleinern(pfadPhoto);
    ...
}
```

and this works without a problem.

Where do you see the error?

Answer (score 0):

> I followed Google's guide Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps

No, you did not. There is no `getRealPathFromURI_API19()` method in that guide. That's for a very good reason: it does not work in general.

So, delete it.

Instead, use your favorite image-loading library to load the image from the `Uri`. Or, in a worst-case scenario, use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then pass that stream to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Just do this I/O on a background thread, please (which image-loading libraries will handle for you, among other benefits).

> and this works without a problem

That is because you have not tested it very much.

I am not quite certain what "a picture selection takes place with the file manager" means. Regardless, your broken `getRealPathFromURI_API19()` assumes that either:

- If you `query()` the `Uri` and get `null` back, then `getPath()` is a filesystem path. There is no requirement for this to be the case. For example, the `Uri` might be served by a `ContentProvider` but one that does not implement `query()`. Or, it might be an `android.resource` scheme (which various developers try). Both of those represent bugs on the sender's part, but your app will still fail.
- If you `query()` the `Uri` and get a `Cursor` back, that cursor will have a `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA` column. There is no requirement for this to be the case. `FileProvider`, for example, does not do this.
- If you `query()` the `Uri` and get a `Cursor` back, and there is a non-`null` `DATA` column, that it represents a filesystem path that you can use. There is no requirement for this to be the case. For example, the path might be to files on removable storage that you have no access to directly via the filesystem.

Fortunately, using `openInputStream()` addresses all of these, as would using a well-maintained image-loading library.